# Java.util.Date not converting properly to Java.time.LocalDate

Tags: java, date, time, localdate

I'm trying to convert java Date to java LocalTime and my code looks like this

```
Date memberBirthdayDate = club.getMembers().get(i).getDob();
        System.out.println(memberBirthdayDate);
        LocalDate memberBirthday = memberBirthdayDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

When I print out the date before and after converstion it looks like this:

```
Before: Wed May 21 00:00:00 GMT 94
After: 0094-05-18
```

It looks like it's converting backwards but I can't work out how to do it!

Comment: It’s a Gregorian/Julian difference. Look it up if you don’t know about it. `LocalDate` uses the proleptic Gregorian calendar. I’m not sure what `Date` uses. For dates back in year 94 AD (more than 1900 years ago) you shouldn’t be surprised about May 21 coming through as May 18.

Comment: You either got some very old club members ([Emperor An of Han](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emperor_An_of_Han)?) or a bug in your years. Maybe you intended 1994 instead?

Comment: @OleV.V. That's it! I'd imported from a csv through Excel and it had automatically formatted the date to remove the '19'... Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

you can do that

```
 LocalDateTime memberBirthday = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(memberBirthdayDate.toInstant(), 
ZoneId.systemDefault());
Date out = Date.from(memberBirthday.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()); System.out.println(out);
```

Comment: That doesn’t seem to produce the `LocalDate` that was asked for? And also doesn’t seem to address neither the issue of May 21 becoming May 18, nor that of 1994 becoming just 94?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in your years. You gave the answer yourself in the comment:

> I'd imported from a csv through Excel and it had automatically
>   formatted the date to remove the '19'

The conversion you made works nicely for a date in 1994:

```
    System.out.println("Before: " + memberBirthdayDate);
    LocalDate memberBirthday = memberBirthdayDate.toInstant()
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .toLocalDate();
    System.out.println("After: " + memberBirthday);
```

Output:

```
Before: Sat May 21 00:00:00 IST 1994
After: 1994-05-21
```

I used Europe/Dublin time to reproduce your exact result, so IST is for Irish Summer Time. Your `Date` seems to denote the start of day at some GMT offset, so you need to use a time zone that agrees with this offset. I expect the conversion to work as expected at least for all dates after year 1900, and likely earlier too.

However, when the year gets truncated from 1994 to 94, funny things start to happen. Dates that far back are not so well defined. `LocalDate` uses the proleptic Gregorian calendar, which is practical and well-defined, but doesn’t agree with dates used in real life before the introduction of the Gregorian calendar from 1582 and on. I’m not sure what `Date` uses. For dates back in year 94 AD we shouldn’t be surprised about May 21 coming through as May 18.

```
Before: Wed May 21 00:00:00 GMT 94
After: 0094-05-18
```

**Link:** [Wikipedia article *Gregorian calendar*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar)